# how to trigger page reload on previously action

Tags: amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

How do I may trigger an page reload based on some previously action on AMP Page?

In concrete terms I want to achive that after user consent has been obtained, the page should immediately reload itself and display related content.

Currently the page content do not change after requesting the consent, and one may have the impression that nothing has changed. 
Once the user returns to the page, or reload the page by himself, the changes takes effect.

A rapid response would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean : https://ampbyexample.com/user_consent/amp-user-notification_with_server_endpoint/

Comment: @Lovntola, not quite, we are using amp-consent element: https://ampbyexample.com/user_consent/basic_user_consent_flow/

Comment: can you add the 'a'-tag with the same url between the button-tag, to 're'load the page?

Comment: @Lovntola, this is exactly the question. But I do not want the user to click on another button. The reload action should be bound to the current one.

Comment: I mean put the the link inside the acept button. but you aright its a stupid solution.